# Are Stack Overflow sites able to track the visit from a user before he/she logs in?

Tags: support, login, logout

I logged in to Server Fault for the first time, and I noticed that I am reported to have visited Server Fault 4 days ago.

As far as I remember, I have never logged in to Server Fault before. Is this possible, or did I really log in to Server Fault and visited the site 4 days ago (maybe before I formatted my Mac, and reinstalled Mac OS X 10.6)?

Comment: It was the second time, but you're right: according to your history (visible to mods only), you have only visited Server Fault on the day you created the account in December and today. I guess you've found a bug.

Comment: Should I change the question to a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is certainly possible in an ASP.NET app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx#S6) like Stack Overflow. And [anonymous users do have an "account" of a sort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon), so the behavior you describe doesn't seem unreasonable.